# How can I create a variable only if an object property exists?

Tags: php, oop, object, variables

I am creating the variable "template" from an object:

```
$templateId = $page->getTemplate()->getId();
```

But in some cases "template" does not exist in "$page". In this case I want "$templateId" to be empty.

My approach:

```
$templateId = property_exists($page->getTemplate()->getId()) ? $page->getTemplate()->getId() : "";
```

The error:

> Call to a member function getId() on null

Comment: mention your *property_exists()* here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$templateId = $page->getTemplate() ? $page->getTemplate()->getId() : "";
```

Answer (score 4):

`getId()` is not the property. It is the method. You can check method existence with [`method_exists()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php) function

```
$templateId = method_exists($page->getTemplate(), 'getId') ? $page->getTemplate()->getId() : ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `if(obj.propertyname){}`.

That way you can ensure the property must exist.

Answer (score 0):

Just add '@'

```
$templateId = @$page->getTemplate()->getId() ? $page->getTemplate()->getId() : "";
```